# DirectoryEntry() not authenticated

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to use DirectoryEntry to gain access to AD. We have an "OU=Company Users" and then and "OU=Applications". My personal user account is in the Company Users OU and when trying `return new DirectoryEntry(Path,UserName,Password,Secure)` it works when I use my personal credentials. I would accept that and go on with life but I am not willing to place my credentials in a config file and keep it up to date for the life of the project.

So we created a new account located in the Applications OU. I am not sure how to get authenticated with those credentials and still create the DirectoryEntry with the root path to the other OU.

Comment: This question could use a code example.

Comment: Ill add one in later. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OU the account is in has no relation to whether or not you can authenticate to AD with it really. You can just plug the username and password in same as before. Ideally the IIS App Pool would run as this user and you wouldn't even need to store creds or specify them to the directory entry.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: You were right on. Also I had some characters in the password such as \ / so I change it over to a string literal and then the authentication worked. I am currently in dev and running on the Visual Studio IIS so when I go prod Ill use the suggested App Pool setup. Thanks again!